# CSS to emulate the fade of opacity without actually reducing opacity?

Tags: css, filter, opacity, color-theory

Can this be done? Would I be wasting precious time even trying to string filters together in such a way as to emulate this, such as via CSS filters?

Similar questions I saw are filled with answers over half a decade old.

Comment: But why?

If you meant, faking the opacity of an image without actually reducing its opacity then you need to place a div on top of it, make it fill all the space of the image then reduce that div's opacity but I don't know what you are trying to do so I don't know if this would help you.

Comment: Actually our purpose is to make a fade transition between elements. We use opacity over a white background for this mostly, but for these particular elements which overlay those - the opacity over opacity creates a very messy look. Mostly working with text here, not images, which is why the opacity creates such a messy look.

Comment: Can you post your example code here, any good question on SO has a reproducible example so direct help and answers can be given.

Comment: @NathanielFlick that's an enormous overgeneralization to say _any_ good question has a reproducible example, especially in the case of - "Is this possible?" where of course I will have no example, because if I did I would have no question.

Comment: @Slbox no, it's not, it's part of SO's guidelines for asking a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Sure maybe a better word is "most", didn't mean to offend.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the opacity is basically saying to the renderer ***"mix this element's color with whatever color is behind it".***

It can be done, but the way to do it depends on the use-case, and gets tricky if you don't have a single color to base on.

##### Using filters

Basically you need to interpolate the HSB values from one color to another, depending on how much opacity you want, using a mix of `hue-rotate`, `saturate` and `brightness`.

##### Using animation

A simple example would be to transition the text color to the same as the background.

```css
div {
  width: 250px;
  height: 65px;
  margin: 25px;
  background: #000;
}

h1 {
  animation: fadeToBlack 2s infinite ease-in-out;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  padding: 25px;
}

@keyframes fadeToBlack {
  from {
    color: #FFF;
  }
  to {
    color: #000;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>I'm fading without opacity!</h1>
</div>
```